# need to identify value using two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements, matching

I have a dataframe called data that looks like this:

| org_id | commit_date | commit_amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-06-01 | 50000 |
| 123 | 2020-06-01 | 50000 |
| 123 | 2021-06-01 | 60000 |
| 234 | 2019-07-01 | 30000 |
| 234 | 2020-07-01 | 40000 |
| 234 | 2021-07-01 | 50000 |

I want the dataframe to look like this:

| org_id | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | amt_1 | amt_2 | amt_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-06-01 | 2021-06-01 | 2022-06-01 | 50000 | 50000 | 60000 |
| 234 | 2019-07-01 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-07-01 | 30000 | 40000 | 50000 |

I've gotten the date columns and org_id column by:

```py
    dates = data.groupby('org_id').apply(lambda x: x['commit_date'].unique()) #get all unique commit_date for the org_id
    dates = dates.apply(pd.Series) #put each unique commit_date into it's own column, NaN if the org_id doesn't have enough commit_dates
    c_dates = pd.DataFrame() #create empty dataframe
    c_dates['org_id'] = dates.index #I had to specify each col bc the 
    dates df was too hard to work with.
    c_dates['date_1'] = dates[0].values.tolist()
    c_dates['date_2'] = dates[1].values.tolist()
    c_dates['date_3'] = dates[2].values.tolist()
```

I cannot figure out how to get amt_1, amt_2, and amt_3 columns. I can't just repeat date columns code bc it will miss the repeat 50000 for org_id_123. Bc the c_dates dataframe does not match length of the original data dataframe, I can't just compare c_dates to data.

EXCITING UPDATE!
I haven't totally solved my problem yet, but I have made a bit of progress:

```py
dates = data.groupby(['org_id','commit_amt']).apply(lambda x: x['commit_date'].unique()) #get all unique commit_date for the org_id
dates = dates.apply(pd.Series) #put each unique commit_date into it's own column, NaN if the org_id doesn't have enough commit_dates
```

gives me the data I want, however, it is not formatted how I want. It gives results that look like:

| org_id | commit_amt |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 50000 | 2020-06-01 | 2021-06-01 |
| 123 | 60000 | 2022-06-01 |  |
| 234 | 30000 | 2019-07-01 |  |
| 234 | 40000 | 2020-07-01 |  |
| 234 | 50000 | 2021-07-01 |  |

I would appreciate any help in getting me to the format I want. I ultimately want to be able to take the difference between amt_1 and amt_2, etc.

Hope this makes sense.

P.S. Thanks to the hero who edited this thereby teaching me how to make tables!

EXCITINGER NEWS!! I HAVE SOLVED MY PROBLEM!!!

Long story short, the function I needed was unstack. I am tired now but tomorrow, I will edit this with the solution! w00t!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use pandas.pivot() , for reshaping your date. but there is problem in using pivot() is you must not have duplicated value.
first i think you drop duplicated rows then use pivot.

```
data = data.drop_duplicates()
data.pivot(index='org_id', columns=['commit_amt'], values=['commit_date'])
```

Comment: As I understand, this would take the values in commit_amt and make them the columns of my df and the commit_date would then be the values in the pivot table. This does not get me what I am looking for. I am looking to add commit_amt columns to instead, I'd have:

amt_1 | amt_2 |  amt_3 

instead of one commit_amt column with multiple observations for the same org_id. I want one org_id row and then multiple columns for commit amounts and dates.

This did help me learn about pivots which is one of my weakness though, thanks!